# Would users be able to update if I uploaded an APK when previously we used AAB?

Tags: android, google-play-console

The app originally started with APKs, then we uploaded AABs. But for the most recent release, we had an oversight and uploaded an APK instead of AAB. Will users be able to update? And will they be prompted? I can't test since I do not have the previous version of the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upload and publication flow for both is identical.

as long as it has a higher version code the user will get the update prompt from Play Store